# Off screen element teststack white

Tags: c#, ui-automation, white-framework

I need to automate 3rd party WPF application. I use
TestStack/White. This application has menu bar that is presented by images. After some actions menu is changing. There presents new images. When I want to click on new image:

```
Window mainWindow = application.GetWindow("Main window", InitializeOption.NoCache);
Image newTask = mainWindow.Get<Image>(SearchCriteria.ByControlType(ControlType.Image).AndIndex(2));
newTask.Click();
```

I get exception:

> TestStack.White.AutomationException: Cannot perform action on Image.
>   AutomationId:, Name:, ControlType:image, FrameworkId:WPF, element is
>   offscreen.

I use Microsoft Inspect for research elements.
When I start tests, Inspect show me that image is offscreen. But if I do these actions manually, it works perfectly and in Inspect this image is not offscreen.

How can I refresh these elements or clear cache of window?

Comment: You should perhaps add a Wait call  before clicking the image, to allow the new image to appear on screen.

Comment: I tried to add big Wait. But it doesn't help.

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot of the properties from inspect with the heirarchy?

Answer (score 0):

There are ReInitialize and ReloadIfCached methods on Window object. Try those to see if something changes.

Are you sure AndIndex(2) is correct element in that particular situation?

Try using GetMultiple and iterate the collection to see what images you actually have and which are not Offscreen.

WPF automation with White is pretty hard. Try Telerik Testing Framework and White could be supporting framework. It is much more easier that way.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a problem with focus, try to use this before getting image:

```
mainWindow.Focus(DisplayState.Maximized);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer but the final solution I've got after all these TestStack.White not found elements, table rows, and so on. I started to move it to FlaUI. If something does not work or unstable with White then most likely I can get more stable and fast-executable FlaUI solution.

Fortunatly, such migration can be done with little steps. For example I already have TestStack.White.Application **app**, then I replace White portion of code with FlaUI like this:

```
var flApp = FlaUI.Core.Application.Attach(app.Process.Id);
using (var automation = new UIA3Automation())
{
    // .. new UI element processing
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don’t think that caching is the problem here. You are getting the `mainWindow` with `InitializeOption.NoCache`. In Non-cache mode the controls are found on demand. So I presume that the cache is refreshed automatically. (https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/master/src/TestStack.White/Factory/InitializeOption.cs)

Perhaps the index of the element you want to click is not 2. 
Have you tried adding an explicit wait? It sounds like you have only tried adding an implicit wait.(https://github.com/TestStack/TestStack.docs/blob/master/_source/White/Advanced%20Topics/Waiting.md)